# Making an enum Equatable in Swift

Tags: swift

Here is my sample code for making my enum explicitly conform to Equatable protocol:

```
enum TestEnum: Equatable {

    case one, two, three, four, five

    static func ==(lhs: TestEnum, rhs: TestEnum) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }
    
}
```

I used hashValue to control but I do not understand how could I be able access to hashValue? I mean at least I did not make my enum conform to Hashable, so why should I be able to access to hashValue in first place?!

So my **real question** or issue is this, let say my enum is not conforming to Hashable, how could I return **true** or **false** for **==** function in this case?

So think about in this way we do not have access to `.hashValue`, what could be able do in this case?

**As you can see my enum conform just for Equatable nothing else!**

Comment: An enum without associated values has Hashable conformance even without the declaration -- see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable/

Comment: A enum without associated values is as simple as an Int to the compiler, so it is easy to automatically add .hashValue property to it.

Comment: In question I mentioned explicitly! NOT implicitly, so it means the OP knows that enum can confrom to Equatable without implementing a custom == function, right?  @JoakimDanielson

Comment: @LdBeth: Thanks for Link, where is saying that: An enum without associated values has Hashable conformance even without the declaration? is it in the Link?

Comment: You can manually write a switch statement or something, but that would be tedious, of course. The point is if you don't have special needs (such as making TestEnum.one == TestEnum.two to be True), just use the default functions generated for you.

Comment: @Fullcode under section "Conforming to the Hashable Protocol", bullet point "For an enum, all its ...", in the parentheses ;-)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: Because I should show what I tried to solve the issue by myself and what I tried so far! even if it makes issue or solving nothing! I am trying to get help from your comments, but I could not receive it so far. Any other question?

Comment: @LdBeth: Oh that is right! That is there! thanks. :)

Answer (score 7):

To chime in:

If you *did* want to implement `==` yourself, the way to do it would be with pattern matching. Surprisingly (to me), the code below seems to call neither `~=` nor `==`.

```
enum TestEnum: Equatable {
    case one, two, three, four, five

    static func ==(lhs: TestEnum, rhs: TestEnum) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.one, .one),(.two, .two), (.three, .three), (.four, .four), (.five, .five): return true
        default: return false
        }
    }
}
```

That does kind of make sense. At bottom, you need the system to provide a way to compare these values. If one didn't exist all, it would be impossible for you to build one. By analogy, imagine how you might implement `==` for `Int`, if it wasn't already built-in. It would be impossible.

I'll also add: it doesn't make any sense to implement `==` based off `hashValue`. `hashValue` speeds up search algorithms by allowing them to rapidly cull a massive part of their search space. For example, say you're looking for milk in the grocery store. A good hashValue for a grocery product might be the section its in. If you saw that your milk's hashValue was "dairy", then you know right away that there's no point searching the deli, meat, produce and frozen food isles. But once you're in front of the dairy isle, you start linearly searching through all the items there. This is where `==` comes in. It needs a more granular notion of equality than the heuristic that `hashValue` provides. Butter and milk are both dairy, but you need to be able to discern them apart.

Comment: Thanks, i got a little confused! If you look my question, I showed a way for conformation via using hashValue. I got the feeling that you are saying using hashValue is not the right way. So if we want conform to Equatable explicitly what we should do then? Do we know how conformation to  Equatable implicitly done? If we just add Equatable protocol and do not define == by ourself?

Comment: Also you said: "Surprisingly (to me), the code below seems to call neither ~= nor ==" but your codes works for me, what you mean by that? I put a print("called!") before switch, and it prints when I use == or !=

Comment: “So if we want conform to Equatable explicitly what we should do then?” Isn’t that precisely what my answer already demonstrates?

Comment: I really don’t understand the question here. “If we want to conform to equatable explicitly”. There is no need. You get that for free anyway. It makes no sense to worry about how to conform to equatable explicitly. Because it already confirms to equatable. The reason you seem to not be satisfied with the answers you are getting is because your question makes no sense right now. Perhaps there is some underlying question that you want to ask other than this?

Comment: @Fogmeister I disagree. I think it's a perfectly valid question. If we say "the conformance to Equatable is synthesized for you", it's really naturally to want to know "what would that look like, and how could I write it myself if I wanted to". I think we should be promoting this deeper-than-surface level understanding.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn’t see it as that question but now you have said it I guess you can see it like that. I guess the issue with the question as it is worded is that it is using enum which has “special powers” granted by the compiler. So you can do things like this and you will not see how it is really working.

Answer (score 6):

An enum without associated values conforms implicitly to Equatable **and** Hashable.

From the documentation:

[Hashable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable/)

> When you define an enumeration without associated values, it gains Hashable conformance automatically, and you can add Hashable conformance to your other custom types by implementing the `hash(into:)` method.

[Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable)

> An enum without associated values has Equatable conformance even without the declaration.

If you don't trust the documentation prove it:

```
enum TestEnum {
    case one, two, three, four, five
}
```

Equatable:

```
TestEnum.one == TestEnum.one // true
TestEnum.one == TestEnum.three // false
```

Hashable:

```
let dict : [TestEnum:Int] = [.one:1, .two:2]
// compiles, a dictionary key must be hashable
```

And `hashValue` is discouraged in Swift anyway.

Comment: OP will be very angry with this answer :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't care. 

Comment: No, :) I can wait for the answer I need! @JoakimDanielson

Comment: @Fullcode is the answer you need not the same as the correct answer?

Comment: @Fogmeister: Thanks being worry about my question! :) I think you can extract your question answer from my last comment on this Answer.